# Custom post type and permalink issue

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a custom post type "goal" setup. Regular posts are assigned to each goal, resulting in permalinks like http://example.com/credit/fix-my-credit/learn-how (format is `%category%/%goal%/%postname%`) where:

- category (slug) = 'credit'
- goal (slug) = 'fix-my-credit'
- post (slug) = 'learn-how'

The permalinks work for the most part. However, in the admin side, for example when editing a post the permalink is correct at the top of the edit page, but the "View Post" link in the top admin bar looks like http://example.com/credit/%goal%/learn-how.  I see the same thing in links under recent comments on the admin dashboard.  Setup:

Settings >> Permalink >> Custom Structure: `/%category%/%goal%/%postname%/`

Custom Post:

```
    $labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Goals', 'Post Type General Name', 'bonestheme' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Goals', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'bonestheme' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Goals', 'bonestheme' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Goals', 'bonestheme' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Goal Archives', 'bonestheme' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Goal:', 'bonestheme' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Goals', 'bonestheme' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Goal', 'bonestheme' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Goal', 'bonestheme' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Goal', 'bonestheme' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Goal', 'bonestheme' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Goal', 'bonestheme' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Goal', 'bonestheme' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Goals', 'bonestheme' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'bonestheme' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'bonestheme' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'bonestheme' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'bonestheme' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'bonestheme' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'bonestheme' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'bonestheme' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'bonestheme' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'bonestheme' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'bonestheme' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'bonestheme' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Goals', 'bonestheme' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'bonestheme' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'tag' ),
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'goal', 'with_front' => false ),
);
```

Rewrite:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
add_rewrite_rule(
        '^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?', 
        'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&goal=$matches[2]&goal_article=$matches[3]', 
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Permalink filter:

```
function update_article_permalink( $permalink, $post_id ) {
global $post;
    if ( get_post_type($post_id) === 'post' ) {
        $the_goal = get_article_goal($post_id);
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $post->post_name = sanitize_title($post->post_title);
        $post_link = $permalink;

        if (!empty($the_goal)) {
            $goal_slug = $the_goal['slug'];
            $post_link = str_replace( '%goal%', $goal_slug, $permalink );
        } else {
            $slug = $post->post_name;
            $post_link = str_replace( '%goal%/', '', $permalink );
        }
        $permalink = $post_link;
    }

    if (  get_post_type($post_id) === 'goal' ) {
        $categories = get_the_category($post_id);
        if (count($categories) > 0){
            $first_cat = $categories[0]->slug;
            $permalink = preg_replace( '(\/goal\/)', '/'.$first_cat.'/', $permalink );
        }
    }

    return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'get_sample_permalink', 'update_article_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

What have I missed? How can I get `%goal%` replaced in all permalinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter for `post` permalinks is [`post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/).

Hook your `update_article_permalink` function to the `post_link` filter to apply your function whenever `get_permalink` is called.

Comment: You got me on the right path - looks like there are a couple other customizations (that I inherited) that were affecting the EDIT POST page negatively.  I'll update the question with the solution and then accept your answer!